# Django queryset window aggregates

Tags: python, django, database, django-queryset

I have a fairly simple model, let's call it `Metric`:

```py
class Metric(models.Model):
    metric_1 = models.FloatField()
    ...
```

Now suppose there is a metric for each day and person, and I have an endpoint that calculates the average of those metrics over a given period, and the change compared to the previous month. A straight forward (but probably inefficient?) approach:

```py
def calculate_aggregates(self, previous_start, start, end, member):
        
    metrics = DailyLoadDataMetric.objects.filter(target_member=member, 
                  target_date__gte=previous_start, 
                  target_date__lte=end)

    previous_metrics = metrics.filter(target_date__lte=start)
    current_metrics = metrics.filter(target_date__gte=start)

    curr_aggregates = current_metrics.aggregate(
                        average_metric_1=Avg('metric_1')))

    prev_aggregates = previous_metrics.aggregate(
                        average_metric_1=Avg('metric_1'))
        
    aggregates = {
            'average_metric_1': curr_aggregates['average_metric_1'],
            'average_metric_1_change': ((curr_aggregates['average_metric_1'] / prev_aggregates['average_metric_1']) - 1.0) * 100,
        }
        

    return aggregates
```

It seems that something like this could be performed by completly by the database. But how? Specifically since I need the average value from the previous month, I have to perform two `aggregate` calls, hitting the db twice. I have looked into window functions, but it seems they can only be used with `annotate`, which does not seem like the thing I want.

Is there something that takes an entire queryset, and calculates aggregates based on a given partitioning? In this case, it could even be a fixed number of rows, because I know I have one `Metric` row for each day.

Edit: Is there a way to use "multiple" partitions? So that I don't only partition for the member but also for the months?

Comment: convert the output from metrics query in to a data frame  using pandas , then you can play with your data as you like and only one call is made to DB

Comment: But which will be mor efficient, given that both the DB and django run on the same server? (Mysql)

Comment: you have to hit the db at least once to get the initial data, convert in to a data frame and use it accordingly

Comment: You can do it in one shot (using `case`) instead of two shots as now, but, in my opinion, is cheapest to do it with two queries. Using two queries, you avoid scanning on result about date ranges. If do you have the right index ( member, date ) make two queries is more index friendly.